# error: int cannot be deferenced

Tags: rest, java-ee, wildfly

Tengo el siguiente trozo de codigo preteneciente a un servicio REST creado automaticamente por Netbeans 8.2 luego de haber creado las entidades usando la Base de Datos.

```
  @POST
@Consumes({MediaType.APPLICATION_XML, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON})
@Transactional

public Response create(Butaca entity) {
    entityManager.persist(entity);
    return Response.created(URI.create(entity.getButacaPK().getIdButaca() + "," + entity.getButacaPK().getIdSector().toString())).build();
}
```

No identifico como solucionar el error del Int.

**Editado**
En la linea Return dice *int cannot be deferenced*, pero no puedo identificar cual Int. 
Agrego captura con el error.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Que error te esta dando? Podrias añadirlo a la pregunta?

Comment: Ya lo edite... espero que responda tu consulta.

Answer (score 1):

Estaba convirtiendo mal a String... quedo de la siguiente manera:

```
return Response.created(URI.create( Integer.toString(entity.getButacaPK().getIdButaca() )+ "," + entity.getButacaPK().getIdSector() ) ).build();
```

se agrego **Integer.toString** al comienzo del create y se elimino el **toString** al final.